# Delete rows in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have tow tables

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

How to make pl/SQL procedure and then job when I delete from table1 where table1.S = Table2.Z and table1.O =90 and table2.P=90 same time to delete in table2

Comment: Is there any constraint of 1 table over another? We need to know that first!

Comment: Perhaps do a couple tutorials on SQL would be a good start

Comment: i haven't privilege for constraints,some how if not exist in S where O=90 to delete Z where P=90

Answer (score 0):

**Create trigger for after delete event:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_aftre_table1
AFTER DELETE
  on table1
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

-- Delete from table2 when delete ant data from table1
delete from  table2  where :OLD.S = Table2.Z and :OLD.O=table2.P ;    
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be a *trigger*, not a *procedure + job*.

Here's an example: sample tables & trigger code, which specifies *WHEN* to fire:

```
SQL> create table t1 as
  2    select 50 s, 90 o from dual union
  3    select 51, 90 from dual union
  4    select 50, 10 from dual;

Table created.

SQL>  create table t2 as
  2    select 50 z, 10 p from dual union
  3    select 51, 10 from dual union
  4    select 50, 90 from dual union
  5    select 51, 90 from dual;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ad_t1
  2    after delete on t1
  3    for each row
  4    when (old.o = 90)
  5  begin
  6    delete from t2
  7      where z = :old.s
  8        and p = :old.o;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

OK, some deleting: first, one that won't affect TABLE 2:

```
SQL> delete from t1 where s = 50 and o = 10;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * From t1;

         S          O
---------- ----------
        50         90
        51         90

SQL> select * From t2;

         Z          P
---------- ----------
        50         10
        50         90
        51         10
        51         90

SQL>
```

And now, the one that affects TABLE 2:

```
SQL> delete from t1 where s = 50 and o = 90;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * From t1;

         S          O
---------- ----------
        51         90

SQL> select * From t2;

         Z          P
---------- ----------
        50         10
        51         10
        51         90

SQL>
```